# Gluon Mobile project builds native-image but fails to run it (on Linux)

Tags: gluon-mobile, graalvm-native-image

I am testing the Gluon Mobile framework, and have made a small application based on the *Afterburner with FXML* template from the IntelliJ Idea Gluon plugin.

The application builds and runs successfully on the JVM and I am also able to build a native image (`./gradlew nativeBuild` on Linux with `GRAALVM_HOME` pointing to 20.3.0.r11-grl).

When I try to run the native image (with `./gradlew nativeRun`) it fails with `javafx.fxml.LoadException: biz/nellemann/pwgen/views/main.fxml`. Maybe related to `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.Slider`?

I have looked through the Gluon docs and searched for similar errors, but have not been able to solve my problem. I hope someone can take a look and enlighten me.

The full trace can be seen at https://pastebin.pl/view/f75a0138, and the source for my test project is available at https://bitbucket.org/mnellemann/pwgen-gluon/.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: Just add `javafx.scene.control.Slider` to the `reflectionList`. See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_reflectionlist. Most of the JavaFX core classes are already added to the list, but some are still missing.

Comment: Thank you @JoséPereda. Probably stupid question, but where is this file located and what syntax should I use? By looking at the documentation you linked to (thanks), it points to a file under *target/* - I'm thinking the file should be somewhere under *src/* ?

Comment: If you are using gradle, the file is under `build/client/...`. It is generated on every build, taking into account your reflection list array.

Comment: I switched to Maven, and native-image works, after I added *javax.scene.controlSlider* to the reflection list in pom.xml. I tried the similar trick in build.gradle first, but I ran into other errors and gave up.